# catboost model can not be read anymore in onnxruntime

Tags: catboost, onnxruntime

I am new to using `onnxruntime` and am using my friend's old code to evaluate some data on the `torch` and `catboost` binary classification models in `C++`. The code was working nicely with `onnxruntime v1.6.0` but when I updated it to `v1.14.0`, the `catboost` model does not work anymore.

I save the `catboost` model as the documentation dictates (same as before):

```
model.save_model(
    f'{filename}',
    format="onnx",
    export_parameters={
        'onnx_domain': 'ai.catboost',
    }
)
```

When initialising the `onnxruntime` in `C++`, the `onnxruntime` error complains `what(): Input is not of type sequence or map`. We prepare outputTypes in this way:

```
Ort::TypeInfo typeInfo = _session->GetOutputTypeInfo(i);
if (typeInfo.GetONNXType() == ONNX_TYPE_SEQUENCE) { // <- for a catboost model
    const OrtSequenceTypeInfo *sequence{};
    Ort::ThrowOnError(Ort::GetApi().CastTypeInfoToSequenceTypeInfo(typeInfo, &sequence));
    OrtTypeInfo *sequenceTypeInfo{};
    Ort::ThrowOnError(Ort::GetApi().GetSequenceElementType(sequence, &sequenceTypeInfo));
    Ort::TypeInfo sequenceElementInfo = Ort::TypeInfo{sequenceTypeInfo};
    if (sequenceElementInfo.GetONNXType() == ONNX_TYPE_TENSOR) {
        _outputNodeTypes.push_back(ONNX_TYPE_SEQUENCE);
    } else {
        _outputNodeTypes.push_back(ONNX_TYPE_MAP);
    }
} else {
    _outputNodeTypes.push_back(ONNX_TYPE_TENSOR); // <- for a torch model, which is just a tensor and works fine with both ort versions
}
```

The code actually breaks when accessing output values:

```
if (_outputNodeTypes.front() == ONNX_TYPE_MAP) {
    Ort::Value &value = outputTensors.front();
    Ort::Value map = value.GetValue(0, allocator); // <-- This line causes Ort::Exception()
    Ort::Value mapValue = map.GetValue(1, allocator);

    auto probabilities = gsl::span<float>(mapValue.GetTensorMutableData<float>(), 2);
    return probabilities[1];
}
```

If I print out the type of `value` just before the crash, `onnxruntime v1.6.0` gives me `ONNX_TYPE_SEQUENCE`, while `onnxruntime v1.14.0` gives me `ONNX_TYPE_TENSOR` and the exception is raised.

Anybody has an idea what `onnxruntime` change causes that issue and how to overcome it? To summarize, the same `catboost` model works fine with `onnxruntime v1.6.0` but does not work with `onnxruntime v1.14.0`.

`catboost` model is available [here](https://cernbox.cern.ch/s/sdFdShXBUVPHztC).

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the answer. The `onnxruntime` `Run` function changed its output. According to [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/issues/4620), the first element that is returned from `Run` is indeed `ONNX_TYPE_TENSOR`, so when I changed the `value` assignment from

```
Ort::Value &value = outputTensors.front();
```

to

```
Ort::Value &value = outputTensors[1];
```

it worked as it should.